# Mic not working on Ubuntu 20.04 in Mac Mini (late 2014)

Tags: sound, mac, 20.04, microphone, apple

Just got the new Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my mac mini, and everything is working smoothly, except for the mic. Even when I connect my bluetooth headsets, it doesn't send any sound. It doesn't have an incorporated mic, so it always has to go, either through headset 3.5mm or Bluetooth.
[You can check it just says "Microphone".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LJFZ.png)

I have tried working around with the
[Jack retasking for HDA Intel sound cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjCSN.png), without success.

Any ideas? I really need this for my work calls.

Thanks beforehand.